# Bring object (ListView) to front doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, listview, panel, bringtofront

I do have less space on my WinForm, I want to bring a ListView to the front, but it always stays behind the other panels... I've tried a lot of things, e.g. the command `.bringToFront` order the button bring to front.

[image: screenshot]

In the picture you can see the colored areas (panels) and the white area (ListView). My goal is to make the ListView bigger with the mouse-move-event and make it smaller with the mouse-leave-event.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Actually, the ListView is hosted by the first Panel. In the designer, move the ListView away, select all the panels and position them over the ListView. Or change the panels to labels.

Comment: That helps! Thank you very much!

Comment: Most welcome buddy.

Comment: You should learn how to use the Document Outline window in VS. It will show you the z-order and the parent/child relationships between controls and allow you to manipulate both. Also, if you can't drag and drop controls without accidentally changing their parent, use the Properties window to set the `Location` explicitly.